# Dew on the grass

Tags: weather

A large drop of dew forms on the very tip a blade of grass.
Dew forms on grass when a blade of grass looses heat by radiation from its whole surface and is cooled down to the dew point of the surrounding air. The whole surface is cooled down to the dew point.
Why is the dew not distributed evenly over the whole surface?

Comment: "It may be observed that, when dew drops form, although they may be positioned randomly on flat leaves, they tend to accumulate at the pointed ends of thin, slightly conical growths. We discuss here the basic physics leading to this phenomenon." from http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/la203316k

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this interesting paper by Martin Shanahan. I can see that surface tension would pull water towards the tip of a blade of grass. Is this the whole story or is there also a tendency for more water vapour to condense at the edges and tip of a blade of grass than on other parts of the grass blade?

Comment: In the Shanahan paper the "actual mechanism of depositing of liquid from the vapor is not considered" but random deposition is assumed, using the distribution of dew on a flat leaf as evidence.

Answer (score 1):

> A large drop of dew forms on the very tip a blade of grass. Dew forms on grass when a blade of grass looses heat by radiation from its whole surface and is cooled down to the dew point of the surrounding air. The whole surface is cooled down to the dew point. Why is the dew not distributed evenly over the whole surface?

Water molecules are cohesive, in other words sometimes  they stick to each other more than they stick to another object.

> If water molecules stuck to each other in preference to anything else, then drying yourself with a towel would be impossible. Some materials are hygroscopic, and some are hygrophobic. You have to consider the interaction of water molecules and the water-repelling leaf. Thank you to Suzu Hirose for pointing this out.

[image]

Those molecules at the surface of the water layer on the leaf lack water molecules surrounding them and they develop a tendency to cohere to water molecules below and beside them. This causes the water to pull itself into a ball/ spherical shape.

A water drop occurs in the lowest potential energy state, where the mimimum energy is used to maintain the shape. As I stated above, this occurs when cohesive forces for the water pull it together. In a gravity field, such as on  Earth,  the sphere is pulled from a sphere into the drop shape we observe on the leaf.

[image]

Images Sources: [Water Drops on Leaves](http://sophiebenoitstudio.blogspot.ie/2014/11/dew-drop-on-leaf-wallpaper.html)

Comment: If water molecules stuck to each other in preference to anything else, then drying yourself with a towel would be impossible. Some materials are hygroscopic, and some are hygrophobic. You have to consider the interaction of water molecules and the water-repelling leaf.

Comment: Hi Suzu you are 100 percent correct and I am too sleepy to get it right. I will edit the post and if you don't mind I will include your attributed comment . Thank you for spotting it. Btw, I liked your meta post on http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9297/please-re-examine-this-question    it's not often someone does that and I think you were good to make the effort to raise it,   Regards